# Java BitShift difference between 32 and 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, jvm, bit-manipulation, 32bit-64bit

I'm currently migrating a Java Application from 32 to 64 bits and I wanted to know if there is a behavior change with the different binary operators when switching between 32 and 64 bit jvm, more particularly the bit shift operators (`<<`, `>>` and `>>>`).

Thanks!

Comment: No. That is what 'V' in "JVM" stands for (virtual). Write once, run anywhere.

Comment: No difference.  The underlying types int and long haven't changed size, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java language and the JVM are a *standards-based platform.*  The way that standard works is that programs written on it should behave the same, regardless of the underlying hardware platform on which they are run.

Therefore, a bitshift in Java should behave the same whether you run it on a 32 bit machine or a 64 bit machine.  The data types (and their behavior) are defined by the language specification, not the underlying hardware platform.

Comment: can you provide your resource?

Comment: The Java and JVM standards are my resource.

Comment: can you please provide the link for sake of completeness ?

Comment: The Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.  Long answer: noooooooo.

All Java primitive operations are independent of the word size of both the JVM and the underlying machine.